# Find where column comes from within query window with SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Let's say I have this query in *SSMS*:

```
select 
[Cars Sold],
[Cars In Lot],
[Available Cars],
[Car Models]
from
Cars c inner join CarDetails cd on 
c.CarId = cd.CarId
inner join MoreCarDetails mcd on
c.CarId = mcd.CarId
inner join ymcs on 
c.CarId = ymcs.CarId
```

Within the *query window* and without having to query all the tables or run a script that searches for column names, how can I know which table or alias the column `[Cars Sold]` belongs to?

If I place the cursor over the column, I'll see a popup with the column type, like this: `Column Cars Sold (nvarchar(20), null)`, but it doesn't show the table name.

Comment: T-SQL is the dialect of SQL but what (R)DBMS are you using? T-SQL is used by several products, such as SyBase, SQL Server and Azure Synapse.

Comment: Why not properly prefix your columns as you code and then you can *easily* see what object the column comes from as it's actually in the code. Prefixing is a good habit and avoids simple errors and mistakes.

Comment: I'm using SSMS.

Comment: SSMS is the IDE; at least that rules out SyBase.

Comment: I'll tell that to the sql developer that wrote it.

Comment: You really should. Then you wouldn't need to be asking the question; you already have a great example of why qualified columns is only a *good* thing.

Comment: In vanilla SSMS, there's not really an easy way to do. There are paid add-ons (RedGate makes one) that tracks that metadata and displays the sources, otherwise it's down to manually searching

Comment: @ThomA, he left six years ago. You have a better chance of finding him.

Comment: In the meantime, I'll play the cards I've been dealt.

Comment: How do you know that only tables are involved and not views? If the column came from a view and was based on a calculation that involves two tables and another view then would you want to know the name of the (top-most) view?

Answer (score 0):

SSMS does not natively provide a way to expose the table of origin for column names in the way that you are asking (no manual review, no execution of scripts), though a number of add-on solutions exist to provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the Actual Execution Plan and the Output List of each element should tell you.

That's the only way I can think of but it should remind you to ALWAYS use the alias or table name when selecting columns.